# Compactification on $S^n$ and supersymmetry

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, supergravity

Does compactification of $(D+1)$-dimensional supergravities on $S^n$ as 
(1): $\mathbb{R}^{1,D-n}\times S^n$, and (2): $AdS_{D+1-n}\times S^n$
break all of supersymmetery?

My understanding of the case (1) is that since $S^n$ have holonomy group $SO(n)$, and in compact space there are no covariantly constant spinors w.r.t. $SO(n)$, no supersymmetry survives after compactification. Is this argument correct? And does it apply to the case (2) as well?

Comment: With the same topology of sphere, you can get supersymmetry preserving solutions if you allow for what is called as "stretched" and "warped" compactification. Google to get an idea.

Comment: The same one used in flux compactifciations?

Comment: It is actually a little different. The case of stretched sphere is sort of a U(1) bundle over a one dimension lesser space, discussed in http://inspirehep.net/record/204555?ln=en and the case of warp compactification is much complicated but is known to yield supersymmetric compactification with $G_2$ symmetry group. I dont have a reference for that right now though.

Comment: I was actually dealing with this paper: http://inspirehep.net/record/207881/?ln=en , where they preserve SUSY by admitting SU(2) instantons, which leads to two solutions to Einstein eqs: round and squashed $S^7$ spheres. I wonder if it is related to that paper in your reference (cannot access it)

Comment: Those are Englert- type solution with non-vanishing photon curl. The ones I said have different building blocks and correspond to a U(1) bundle construction and warping of Ads metric. A good reference I believe is 'Kaluza- Klein supergravity' by Pope.